# Issue on Encapsulation

Tags: java, encapsulation

Im working through a computer science study gruide right now and ive come across an interesting answer to this question. Apparently the answer is E, but I disagree due to encapsulation. Any reason why the answer is E rather than C?

> A class Particle has a private field double velocity and public
>   methods double getVelocity() and void setVelocity(double v). It also
>   has a method public void hit(Particle p) { < Missing statements > }
>
> Which of the following could replace < Missing statements > in hit to
>   make it compile with no errors?

I.

```
 double v = getVelocity();
  setVelocity(p.getVelocity());
  p.setVelocity(v);
```

II.

```
  double v = velocity;
  velocity = p.getVelocity();
  p.setVelocity(v);
```

III.

```
  double v = velocity;
  velocity = p.velocity();
  p.velocity = v;
```

A. I only

B. II only

C. I and II

D. II and III

E I, II and III

Comment: If code in III were `p.getVelocity()` instead of `p.velocity()`, it would be right. If it's a typo, then fix it. Otherwise, you are right, C is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulation is an important tool to allow a class to be the only one responsible for the state of its instances. However, because this is one Particle manipulating the fields of another instance of the same class, it has access to all methods and fields of the other instance (including `private` methods and fields), and the typical concerns about encapsulation do not apply.

A similar case occurs in `equals` method implementations, where an instance of a class often directly compares its fields against the fields of another instance of the same class.

(This assumes that the reference to `velocity()` in III was meant as `getVelocity()`; otherwise, it would presumably be a compilation error.)

Comment: Code in III doesn't compile, there's no `velocity()` method described for `Particle` class.

Comment: @Luiggi This is true, but I attribute that to a transcription error. The OP refers specifically to encapsulation violations instead of missing symbols.

Comment: Assuming it is a typo, then you're right. But if it's not, then C is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although the field `velocity` is encapsulated and declared `private` as per the specification, it is declared inside the `Particle` class. This means that any method declared inside the `Particle` class has access to this value. It is only subclasses of `Particle` and other classes that do not have access to this variable, but `hit()` definitely does have direct access to the variable.

Even different objects of the `Particle` class will have access to the otherwise `private` member.